# Why is a const in a precompiled vanilla JS script not defined in my Rails app, but works when I remove the const keyword

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a vanilla JS file in my assets/javascripts dir, and placed a basic `window.addEventListener(DOMContentLoaded)` function in said file.

Inside the callback function for the event listener, I had `const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');` however, when I viewed the page in my browser/console, `div` was *NOT DEFINED.*

I removed the `const` keyword, but kept everything else, and suddenly, it works.

Why?

Comment: The variable is local to the callback function.

Comment: If you remove the `const` keyword you're assigning a global variable instead of declaring a local variable.

Comment: Set a breakpoint inside the callback function, then you'll be able to access the variable in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let` and `const` are what's called block scope. That means that they can be accessed only from the "area" they are defined, and in sub-sections. Basically, you are paying attention to the curly brackets. In the example below, I'll use `let` instead of `const`, so that I can change values.

```js
var x = 10; // this is global scope and can be seen everywhere
{
    var x = 5; // this is the same x as above because it is global
    console.log(x); // prints 5
}

console.log(x); // still prints 5 because we changed the global x

function test1() {
    var x = "test1"; // this is inside a function so it is function scoped
    console.log(x); // prints "test1";
}

test1(); // prints "Test1" from inside the function
console.log(x); // still prints 5 because the global x is separate from the inside function x
```

If we take that same code and change the `var` to a `let`, this is what happens

```js
let x = 10; // this is global scope and can be seen everywhere
{
    let x = 5; // this is inside brackets, so its a new block. This x is separate from the global x
    console.log(x); // prints 5
}

console.log(x); // prints 10 because we are global again

function test1() {
    let x = "test1"; // this is inside a function so it is function scoped
    console.log(x); // prints "test1";
}

test1(); // prints "Test1" from inside the function
console.log(x); // still prints 10 because we are still at the global block
```

I am guessing you are using the const divs inside the event listener but trying to access the variable at another point:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
  console.log(divs); // prints NodeList [<div>] …
});

console.log(divs); // error
```

The error is happening because `divs` is only accessible inside the function because it's function scope, not global and its inside another block.